# Using sed and find, how do I append to a file only if it contains a certain value?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a whole bunch of files that need a comment added to them.

at the I am using sed like so:

`sed -i '/line1/a line2' *`

which is fine when I want to match line1 and add line2 underneath on every file in my directory, but what about only files which contain a certain parameter?

For example if I wanted to add a comment, but only to files that contain the text:

`add comment here`

I was thinking of maybe doing something like:

`find . -file '*.txt' -exec grep -iR 'add comment here' {} \; -exec sed -i '/line1/a line2/' {}\;`

But this isn't working as expected.

Comment: Do you mean `-type f`? Why are you using `-R` to grep recursively when your `find` will already traverse directories? I think you need `--quiet` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use grep directly to only emit filenames that match your criteria:

```
grep "add comment here" -r . --include \*.txt -l | xargs sed -i '/line1/a line2/'
```

`-r .` has grep recursively search files in the current directory, `--include \*.txt` tells grep to only consider `.txt` files, and `-l` says to only print the names of files that contain the pattern, nothing else.